# Replace method with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

According to the document using `$’` will insert the part of the string that’s after the match. But I'm unable to get it to work.

```js
let myStr = 'My little Alligator later';
console.log(myStr.replace('gator', '$’'));
```

I was expecting output to be "My little Alli later" (replacing `"gator"` with `" later"`, which is a string that comes after the match), but the actual output is `"My little Alli$’ later"`. Why do I see `'$’` in the output?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter). It’s `$'`, not `$’`, and it only works when the first `replace` argument is a RegExp, not a string.

Comment: And it `$'` not `$’`. Curly quotes are generally not used in programming.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Actually, only `$n` requires it to be a RegExp, since there are no capture groups in plain strings.

Comment: The expected result should be `My little Alli later later`.

Comment: @Barmar Oh. In that case, this question is really just caused by a typo…

Comment: @SebastianSimonm but this works, 
let myStr = 'My little Alligator later';
console.log(myStr.replace('gator', '$`'));

Comment: Now you have the correct type of quote

Comment: @Barmar, check output for the above one, it replaces text before the match, and using $’ replaces text after match

Comment: `$\`` gets the string before the match, `$'` gets the string after the match. But `$’` has no special meaning.

Comment: Do you see the difference?

Comment: @Barmar, source - https://alligator.io/js/string-replace/

Comment: That site is wrong, they used improper typesetting of the JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar, could you please provide the working example for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong type of quote. It should be a straight quote, not a curly quote.

```js
let myStr = 'My little Alligator later';
console.log(myStr.replace('gator', "$'"));
```